# insert default text in the middle of posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress includes around 1000 post, I want to add a default text (HTML formatted) in the middle of each post after loading. so in the future may I can change this text at once and show another text instead if I want.

I found functions to add text after & before the posts, but nothing is used to add inside the posts.

I think that I can add the text after 1st `</p>`

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found below code and added to function.php and it works good

```
<?php

//Insert ads after second paragraph of single post content.

add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );

function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {

    $ad_code = '<div>Ads code goes here</div>';

    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 2, $content );
    }

    return $content;
}

// Parent Function that makes the magic happen

function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {

        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }

        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }

    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a common div or marker that you can use to add text after?

Example:

```
<div id="first">Lorem ipsum</div>
<!-- where you want text -->
<div id="second">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Perhaps a jQuery script, added to single.php can work?

```
<script>
$( "#first" ).after( "<p>My inserted text.</p>" );
</script>
```

Comment: may I can add after first </p>

Comment: It depends on where you want to put it. Just ensure that whatever you add it after, it has an ID or class that you can reference in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I think WordPress `shortcodes` can help you with this. In every post you have to mention short code like this. `[Myshortcode]` and than you can define the functionality in your `function.php`.

Simple example

```
//[foobar]
function foobar_func( $atts ){
    return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

> This will create [foobar] shortcode that returns as: foo and bar

here is the [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) for detail description

For jquery based solution to put content after first `p` you can do something like this.

```
$("#mydiv p:first-child").after("<div>Here is my html</div>");
```

Fiddle is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/fr9k5d2u/1/)

Comment: is that means, that I need to edit all the posts I have? there is no thing can work without editing my posts?

Comment: how will you determine  the middle of every post grammatically ? for jquery solution again you have to mention id and class for every post.

Comment: I can use to add the text after 1st string of </p>

Comment: Here is a fiddle for a jquery based solution. http://jsfiddle.net/fr9k5d2u/1/. This will find first `p` tag in your div and add html after that `p`.

Comment: Thanks alot for your support, just I want to know which file on wordpress I should add this code? function.php? or what?

Comment: You have to add this code in single.php file inside your current theme folder. Single.Php is the file that displays the post.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:
1 - Add your HTML code after the post content in a "display: none;" container
2 - Under that container add small javascript:

```
var containerID = document.getElementById("container");
    var middle-Post-Elements = document.getElementsByClassName("middle-Element-class");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < middle-Post-Elements.length; i++) {
      middle-Post-Elements[i].innerHTML = containerID.innerHTML;
    }
```

3 - Now in your post editor just add this HTML tag were ever you want the code to appear:

```
<div class="middle-Element-class"></div>
```